# How to customize the UITableView scrolling in horizontal direction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a requirement to show the table view in horizontal scrolling.

Eg: In 1st page have to show 10 rows, while scrolling (Horizontal) to the 2nd page have to show 10 more rows, like that I have to show.

How can it be possible?

Answer (score 4):

Use a `UIScrollView` and turn on `pagingEnabled`. Then put a `UITableView` on each page.

Comment: ThanQ jtbandes, I added UIScrollView And I did PagingEnabled to YES. But my tableView shows in first page only, while scrolling to second page it shows empty. how can i add tableview in each page?

Comment: Just add multiple table views to the scroll view at different positions. Read the UIScrollView docs.

Answer (score 2):

Picked this up from an Apple engineer at WWDC: Try setting the tableview's transform to rotate it 90 degrees. Let's see, I think it'd be something like:

Objective-C

```
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0 * M_PI / 180); //Convert 90 degrees to radians
```

Swift 4+

```
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90.0 * .pi / 180) //Convert 90 degrees to radians
```

You'll get all the easy view recycling of a tableview, just horizontally. If subviews of each cell need to be oriented normally, just apply a corresponding rotation transform on those in a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: I do not believe you actually read his post. He is actually looking for a sideways scrolling UITableView. JTBandes has the best answer.

Comment: I think it's best not assume what others have read or not read. JTBandes is proposing multiple UITableViews. But "I have a requirement to show *the* table view in horizontal scrolling" and "How to Customize *the* UItableView scrolling in horizontal direction?" suggests a singular tableView oriented in the horizontal. The provided example is also open to interpretation. I think we can agree the question is unclear.

Comment: This is cool - One thing is that if you have index titles, they will be sideways unless you do something custom

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to have scrolling horizontally in table view is.
Add scrollers to your table view rows and set contents size with increasing width and fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing UiTableView inside a superior UICollectionView cells?
I think there is already a topic for my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679338/table-view-inside-of-a-collection-view)

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)