# Table view inside of a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view, and each collection view cell will have a table view which will have different data for each collection view cell. The collection view is done using a storyboard and works fine, but I can not seem to get a UITableView to work inside of it. The Collection view code is below and any help is appreciated. Ideally a technique that allows me to use storyboard to customise the tableview cell, and I am using Swift 4.

```
extension StoryboardViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt 
       indexPath: IndexPath) {
          print("Selected Cell #\(indexPath.row)")
       }
    }

extension StoryboardViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: "CollectionViewCell"), for: indexPath) as! StoryboardCollectionViewCell
        cell.label.text = "Cell #\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("Current centered index: \(String(describing: centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.currentCenteredPage ?? nil))")
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("Current centered index: \(String(describing: centeredCollectionViewFlowLayout.currentCenteredPage ?? nil))")
    }
}
```

And I want to put a table view (list) inside of it like so:

[image: Storyboard layout]

Comment: did you used table view delegates method?

Comment: I did something like that just the reverse way, you can refer the way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484079/reload-collectionviewcell-inside-tableviewcell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UICollectionViewCell` Class should confirm to Protocols, `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

```
import UIKit
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    //MARK: TableViewDelegateAndDataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Configure your cell here
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Finally don't forget to assign TableView DataSource and Delegate in your storyboard

Comment: I made the table view datasource and delegate onto the collection view, should it be on the collection view cell or the whole view controller?

Comment: the delegate should be on collectionView Cell

Answer (score 3):

`UICollectionViewCell` class that is being used should conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols that will initialize the cells in the table view